# How to get All bit field value in SQL Server in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause, bit

I have been searching but still not get the best way to do this

I have a table with `sex` column (`bit`) so the value will be 1/0/null

My stored procedure with parameter `@sex`

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM [dbo].[data] 
 WHERE sex = ISNULL(@sex, sex)
```

When I'm send `@sex` null, the query just give me all data with sex field true and false but not null

Can someone give me a way to get all value ? true,false,null ?

I'm trying using case but not work to, help me

My stored procedure from the last comment

```
select   
    [idUser],   
    [sex] 
FROM    
    [dbo].[data] 
WHERE   
    (@sex IS NULL AND sex is null)
    OR (@sex IS NOT NULL AND sex = @sex)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. assign @sex with 0,1 or null

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT, SEX BIT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(5,NULL)

DECLARE @sex BIT
SET @sex=NULL

SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE @sex IS NULL or sex=@sex
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: The Where clause will evaluate ANY boolean condition. If "@sex" is NULL then the where clause will always return true, effectively ignoring the parameter. If "@sex" is NOT NULL then it will evaluate to the right of the OR and check the value in the table against the parameter.